# Error performing sensitivity analysis on binary integer programming model using LpSolveAPI package in R

Tags: r, lpsolve

I have a basic binary linear programming model with twenty-five constraints and 416 variables. I create the model and solve for an optimal solution, using the LpSolveAPI package, with no problem. However, when I try to run the package's sensitivity analysis functions I receive this error:

'''Error in get.sensitivity.obj(ff.lp) : OPTIMAL solution'''

If the function is run before the model is solved then this error is given:

'''Error in get.sensitivity.obj(ff.lp) : Model has not been optimized'''

There is no reason the solution being optimal should prevent sensitivity analysis. I don't understand what this error is telling me and I can't find the source code of the function to see what conditions are producing this error message.

Can anyone explain why I am getting this error and how to fix it, or otherwise perform sensitivity analysis on a model built with LpSolveAPI package.

Comment: get.sensitity.obj is for linear models.  Yours is integer.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck A linear model can be integer or non-integer in its variables. Likewise an integer model can be linear or non-linear.

Comment: no. A linear model generally refers to a continuous model. It is usually called an integer programming model otherwise.